# Diffie-Hellman key exchange using addition instead of multiplication?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, group-theory

I know that the additive finite group $(Zp,+)$ of prime order $p$ when I perform the Diffie-Hellman key exchange (DHKE) protocol is insecure. I didn't however find many sources online explain why it is insecure. Neither could I find information about what possible attacks can be performed in that case.

Can anybody explain why it is insecure and what possible attacks would be possible if I would use addition instead of multiplication?

Additionally, how can I make both Alice and Bob have the same key when performing the DHKE using $(Zp, +)$?

Comment: See Wikipedia’s [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Multiplicative_inverses_and_the_RSA_algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

Why can't we use $(Z_p,+)$?

In the DH key Exchange Alice and Bob agree on a common generator g which allow to share a common key. In fact in $(Z_p,+)$ every non zero element is a generator.

If a common generator g is preallably chosen, when Alice chose a secret `a`, transmitting `A=g.a`, the secret a will be immediatly disclosed by any one in the public channel by simply Computing $a=\frac{A}{g}$ and key exchange will be violated which isn't the case in $(Z_p,*)$, as the inversion by the discret logarithm, is considered hard.

Comment: interesting, good information to know, thanks. So in Z*p I could calculate A by using this formula A= g^Alice, pr mod p but what about when I use Zp+

Comment: @han, In $(Z_p,+)$ every non zero element is a generator then g.a mean adding a g-times whith itself: $a+a+...+g  = g.a$. which is different from $a*a...*a=g^a$ in  $(Z_p,*)$. Look at the principal definitions inside a group.

Comment: The fact that the discrete logarithm in $(Z_P, +)$ is easy, has nothing to do with the fact that every element is a generator. The discrete logarithm problem is easy in $(Z_P, +)$ because one can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to calculate it.

Comment: Yes, I got all that information. But I want to know if I use Zp+ in DH can I get the same shared key. So I am trying to calculate manually to see by myself. That's why I am asking about the formula, is it different than Z*p

Comment: I use A=a.g mod p in Zp+, and A=g^a mod p in Z*p, right?

Comment: @Cryptostasis, in this additive group there is no discret log. My methodology is to explain simply to han why DH is not pertinent in a additive group structure. To implement DH, you need a generator!

Comment: @han Observe that on set of elements you can define many group structures. And there is some morphism between $(Z_p,+)$ and $(Z_p,*)$ by the mapping $x -> g^x$ where g is a generator of the multiplicative group.

Comment: @Robert: There is a discrete logarithm in every cyclic group, i.e. also in the additive group of a finite field.

Comment: @Cryptostasis, Yes of course but it is a degenerated case as every element is a generator. Remember that Alice never met Bob and then they can't agree on a common generator.

Comment: @Robert: I am not sure what you mean.In many elliptic curve groups, which are used in cryptography, it is the case that every element is a generator.

Comment: I got confused now. in Zp+ I can easily recover the pr by a= A/g, but in Z*p it is difficult to recover the key if p is large enough, it is hard to calculate x= log g B mod p. So there is no log in additive group when attacker attends to recover private key? Also, can Alice and Bob have the same shared key using Zp+ ? what is the formula? is it A=g+a mod p and then calculate shared key K AB= B+a mod p, right?

Comment: There is always a discrete logarithm in $(Z_P, +)$ but the _discrete logarithm problem is not hard_. Therefore it is not usable for cryptography. If you nevertheless want to use it for an insecure  Diffie-Helman, then you must use multiplication, I.e. $A = g*a \bmod p$, $B=g*b \bmod p$ and the common secret will be $ZZ = B*a = A*b \bmod p$.

Comment: @Cryptostasis, thank you for your valuable remark. However the protocol used to implement ECDH is quite different and more difficult. Inverting the mapping d -> d.G on an EC is hard. Why ? because doing addition on an EC need calculations on the ground field. In my sens additive group on an EC isn't a group from a finite field.

Comment: The arithmetic of the elliptic curve group is rather complicated. Please note, the fact that you use the addition symbol $ +$ on elliptic curve arithmetic does in no sense mean that it has something to do with the usual addition in integers or modular integers. It would probably be less confusing to use a completely different symbol instead. But in mathematics the same operator symbols are  often used for very different structures. If you know C++ or C# then think about it as a kind of operator overloading.

Comment: @Cryptostasis of course I agree but speaking of discret log in $(Z_p,+)$ has no sens (this is my opinion). However discret log in $(Z_p,*)$ is well defined. Thank you for your valuable remarks. I hope "han" understand better now.

Comment: In case you need room for extended discussion – this conversation has been [moved to a separate chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47712/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-naciri-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-using-addition). As you might have noticed, the comment area can be rather limiting in both space and usability.